# Unhandled exception in UWP and headless apps

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, iot, headless

I've read a lot about catching unhandled exception in an UWP app. All suggest tu use AppDomain.UnhandledException.  But what to do in a headless application, there is no AppDomain and also no UI-thread.

My app starts several threads, binds to several udp/tcp listeners and makes HTTP requests that may crash. I want to log theses crashes to stabilize the app.

Comment: What about Application.UnhandledException? Wire it up in App.xaml.cs; not sure if it can only handle exceptions on UI thread though.

Comment: This I also read, but not sure if it works for headless apps since I have no UI thread.

Answer (score 3):

Unhandled exception detection is encapsulated in [Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.application) which is typically provided in initial XAML for App.xaml, so headless app can not detect unhandled exception.In fact, headless applications launch at machine startup and run continuously without any process lifetime management resource use limitations.They have a very simple execution model, and without process boundaries.If you want to catch exceptions in headless app,you should add try/catch in your each thread.You can refer [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9950633f-a6ab-4441-98ca-d8e91885ea6b/how-to-handle-applevel-exceptions-in-an-iot-background-task?forum=WindowsIoT) to get some more information.